# Call Future in a callabck method

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a method `createClient` which return `Future` value and this method call another `_getConfig` method which returns a response as a `Function` callback, is there any way that in `createClient` method I can return `Future` from response of `_getConfig` method.

```
Future<String> createClient() async {
  _getSocketConfig((socketConfig) => Future.value(
        socketConfig,
      ));
}

void _getConfig(Function(String) onConfigFetch) async {
    onConfigFetch("profileId");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand, but is it this what you want?

```
Future<String> createClient() async {
  return _getSocketConfig((socketConfig) => Future.value(
        socketConfig,
      ));
}

Future<String> _getSocketConfig(Function(String) onConfigFetch) async {
    return onConfigFetch("profileId");
}
```